# Simultaneously move long list files to new location

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line, filesystems

I'm using a wonderful program called ExifTool to recursively rename a large batch of files.

Here is example usage:

```
$ exiftool -r -ext JPG '-FileName<CreateDate' -d %Y%m%d_%H%M%S.jpg .
Error: './folder1/110310_135433.jpg' already exists - ./folder1/source.jpg
Warning: No writable tags found - ./folder2/110404_095111.jpg
   68 directories scanned
 1650 image files updated
    5 image files unchanged
    2 files weren't updated due to errors
```

When processing very large batches of images, the number of files not updated due to errors is often in the hundreds, therefore moving each file individually with `mv` is out of the question.

I'd like to simultaneously move the files with errors/warnings to a separate directory for further processing.

I need to extract the paths of the problem files from the terminal output and move them together, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

How would I go about this?

For what it's worth, I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will extract the filenames from the errors/warnings of `exiftool` and create a replica directory tree under the folder `unprocessed' with only those files. Didn't try to just move them in a single directory to avoid the risk of overwriting files with the same name but different source dirs.

```
exiftool ... 2>&1 | tee exiftool.log | egrep '^(Error|Warning)' | \
    sed 's/^Error: .* already exists - //;s/^Warning: .* - //' | \
        while IFS= read -r img; do
            rsync -vR -- "$img" unprocessed/
            #rm -v -- "$img"
        done
```

The `sed` part takes into account only the output of the example provided, I'm not familiar with the tool and its possible output messages.

EDIT: The `rm` part is commented out cause you better try this out first.

Answer (score 0):

The ExifTool solution is to add %c to the file name (or %%c in the -d argument).  This will cause a copy number to be added to files with duplicate names.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! I'm afraid I don't see how your answer is relevant. The OP wants to move files that return errors by parsing the ExifTool output. Your answer is about adding a copy number to duplicate files which has nothing to do with what is being asked.